# How Do I Query Firestore To Return A String If The Doc ID Is Equal To Current User

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I write a query for a document ID that is equal has the current user and return a string if the user's ID is the name of any document in a specific collection? I have three collections, admin, student, and preceptor.

I need a user sent to a specific place depending on what collection they are in.

The idea is that if the user is equal to the document ID, then I want to return this string.

This is as far as I understand:

```
firebase.firestore.collection('Admin').where("uid", "==", user.uid)
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

While Firestore does support so-called collection group queries, those only work if the (sub)collections have the same name, so for example, if you have a `history` collection under each user, you could use a collection group query across all `history` collections.

There is no way to query across three collections with different names. Each of those collections will need a separate query.

To be honest though your data model is a bit smelly. It is most common to have a collection of users, that contains all users (admins, students, and preceptors) and then store their role as a field in their document in the `users` collection.

That way you can read their profile with:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc(user.uid)
```

And then dispatch them to the right screen based on the `role` field value in that document.